# Adding Try/Catch to Switch statement in powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

So I have my script completed and it runs as desired. However I'm required to add a try/catch statement that catches a system.outofmemoryexception. I'm having an issue as to where to put it. Every time I place it and try and run it, I get told that i'm missing my Catch or finally block and that I'm missing my Until statement...but I did add it.

```
#Clears powershell command line
Clear-Host
Do 
{
    $Num = Read-Host "Press a corresonding number to generate file output"
    Try 
    {
            Switch ( $Num )  
            {
                1 
                {
                    'Daily Log Generated'
                    #The directory of files with the extenstion .log will be listed and output to a text file 
                    $Dir = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\cf3es\Downloads\Requirements1 -Recurse
                    $List = $Dir | where {$_.Extension -eq ".log"} | 
                                    Out-File 'C:\Users\cf3es\Downloads\Requirements1\DailyLog.txt'
               }
               2 
               {
                   'File List Generated'
                    #The contents of the folder will be listed in alphabetical order and will be output to a text file 
                    $Dir = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\cf3es\Downloads\Requirements1 -Recurse
                    Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = "Name"; Descending = $True}
                    $List = $Dir | 
                                    Out-File 'C:\Users\cf3es\Downloads\Requirements1\C917contents.text' 
              } 
              3 
              {
                  'CPU Info Displayed'
                  #Physical disk usage and CPU time will be displayed every 5 seconds with 4 samples
                  Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 5 -MaxSamples 4
                  Get-Counter "\LogicalDisk(C:)\Disk Reads/sec" -SampleInterval 5 -MaxSamples 4
              }
              4
              {
                  'Running Processes Generated'
                  #All running processes will be displayed in a grid format in decending order
                  Get-Process | 
                  Sort TotalProcessorTime -ea silentlycontinue -descending |
                  Select -Property ID,ProcessName,TotalProcessorTime | 
                  Out-GridView 
             }
         }   
     }
 }
 Catch 
 {
     $ErrorMessage = System.OutOfMemoryException
 }
 Until ($Num -eq 5)           
 #this will exit the script
```

Comment: Usually better to put the try-catch block in a process you know that could fail. Not to mention you aren't handling it at all, just setting the error message to what the error is. Introduction guide on how to write try-catch blocks: `https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-using-try-catch-finally-blocks-for-powershell-error-handling/`

Comment: For handling the error, *Go to wsman directory*: `cd wsman:` *Get current size (max) which shell can be*: `$size = Get-Item localhost\shell\maxmemoryperShellMB` *Increase size of shell*: `Set-Item localhost\shell\MaxmemoryPerShellMB $($size + 100)` Can run check against possible memory vs what is being used by powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove a `}` before the catch block and add a `}` after the catch block.

```
Do 
{
   Try 
   {
       Switch ( )  
       {
       }
   }
}
Catch 
{
}
Until ()
```

Code with interior removed, the catch is outside of try block. This is why I format my code very rigorously, as it helps prevent errors like this from happening.

Comment: This helped! I appreciate it.